# How to return zero - Django annotation Count date range

Tags: django, postgresql, python-2.7

The code attached doesn't return zero values for each day of a date range (15 to 19) How can I return zero values :

results expected :

```
[{'day': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 16),'name':'ramu','count': 1},
{'day': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 17),'name': 'raju','count': 0},
{'day': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 18),'name': 'rani','count': 2}]
```

But :( I'm getting following output without zero (0) count.

```
[{'day': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 16),'name':'ramu','count': 1},
{'day': datetime.datetime(2018, 7, 18),'name': 'rani','count': 2}]
```

Code

```
Form.objects.filter(datetime__range=(first_date,last_date)).order_by('datetime').extra(select={"day": "DATE(datetime)"}).values('day','name','count').annotate(count=models.Count("id"))
```

Comment: Well there is no `qst` so according to the table that date does not exists...

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem done please check now . Thats just an example

Comment: @AnishMenon where you get this `count`? from your `field` or from `annotate(count=Count('`?

Comment: from annotate only @SancaKembang